# Questions about the Gravitron ride and how centripetal force works

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Hi just have a basic question. Just went to the local fair yesterday and road the Gravitron ride.  The ride that sucks you to the walls.  I became curious on the physics that cause you to get stuck to the wall so I have been researching centripetal force.  Now it seems that the seats are exerting a force on me directly towards the center of a circle.  I also understand that if hypothetically all of a sudden the walls disappeared on the ride I would move perpendicular to the force (tangental to the point on the circle).  To me this makes little sense as I always thought I would move in a straight line directly in the opposite direction of the center of the circle.  IF you have a force pushing you towards the center wouldn't that mean you would fly away from the center in a straight line assuming the walls suddenly disappeared.  Please clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

Your momentum, at any given time, is in a straight line, in the straight-line direction you were spinning; this is the momentum that holds you against the wall, creating centripetal force.

The sense of being pressed straight outward is because the motion is curved; the correction to your momentum caused by the wall is in the direction of the center of the circle.  If you draw a circle, and draw a line along one tangent (your momentum now), and then the next tangent (your momentum in a moment), the center of the angle between them is pointed directly at the center; this is the direction of force necessary to change the path to keep you in place.